# How do I get the programs on the start menu on Windows 8 that are missing from install, that are there on Windows 7

Tags: windows-8

I've just got a new computer with Windows 8 installed, and I'm not happy that the Start Menu is missing some items. Stuff like Disk Defragmenter, Disk Cleanup, System Restore and other System Tools are gone, and maybe some other things under Accessories.

How can I get them back?

Answer (score 1):

All items are there... If you have Windows 8, you have to right-click on an empty space in the start menu and choose Show All Items, or if you have Windows 8.1, click on the arrow down in the left bottom corner to show them.

If you're in desktop mode, you can right-click the taskbar and customize the behaviour from Start so that it always shows all items.

The easy way however, the way it works in Windows 7 as well, is to use your keyboard. You simply press the key with the Windows logo (=super key), and you type in what you're looking for, e.g. defragment. Tools like disk defragmenter are not tools that you have to use very often though. If you look in your scheduled tasks, you'll see that this happens automatically.

Comment: Exactly right, also knowing old school commands generally still works or works exactly the same. typing 'Fdisk' will find Disk Defrag, ncpa.cpl will work from the search menu and also the run dialog.